# Python3 Plotly markers always circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have for example the following plotly Scatter(severly stripped from other code, all code available at below repo. This always draws as circles and not as pentagons as symbol=13 should per the documentation.

https://plot.ly/python/reference/

https://github.com/CPDTAC/CPViewInsights_Client/blob/378f4b5583b3263daf6fef56a3c557cd26053e45/cpviewdb.py#L120

I had been using plotly via Dash and this was working. Converted most of it to a pyqt gui and for reasons for which I hope you all can answer, marker symbols aren't working for me.

```
    return_data = []
    policy_times = [some list of tuples]
    policy_trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scattergl(
        x=[i[0] for i in policy_times],
        y=[i[1] for i in policy_times],
        name='Policy Install',
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(symbol=13, size=20))
    return_data.append(policy_trace)
    layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(showlegend=True)
    figure = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=return_data, layout=layout)
    plotly.offline.plot(figure, filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reasoning but this was caused due to using Scattergl instead of Scatter.